# Como contar y recorrer un objeto en PHP

Tags: php

Estimados estaría agradecido de su ayuda, estoy utilizando recursos de una API llamada Chilexpress, la cual devuelve un conjunto de valores como un **Objeto**, estoy ejecutando el siguiente script

```
<?php
require_once "vendor/autoload.php"; require_once "vendor/pear/http_request2/HTTP/Request2.php";
$request = new Http_Request2('https://testservices.wschilexpress.com/georeference/api/v1.0/regions');
$url = $request->getUrl();

$headers = array(
    // Request headers
'Cache-Control' => 'no-cache',
'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key' => '9cf7691f40a445009a68c0b9e013b5d1',
);

$request->setHeader($headers);
$request->setMethod(HTTP_Request2::METHOD_GET);

try
{
    $response = $request->send();
    $regiones = $response->getBody();
    var_dump($response);
}
catch (HttpException $ex)
{
    echo $ex;
}
```

el cual me devuelve lo siguiente

object(HTTP_Request2_Response)#6 (9) { ["version":protected]=> string(3) "1.1" ["code":protected]=> int(200) ["reasonPhrase":protected]=> string(2) "OK" ["effectiveUrl":protected]=> string(68) "https://testservices.wschilexpress.com/georeference/api/v1.0/regions" ["headers":protected]=> array(5) { ["transfer-encoding"]=> string(7) "chunked" ["content-type"]=> string(31) "application/json; charset=utf-8" ["request-context"]=> string(49) "appId=cid-v1:271e8bab-af71-4e60-a7f0-213a92306190" ["api-supported-versions"]=> string(3) "1.0" ["date"]=> string(29) "Sat, 25 Sep 2021 00:54:16 GMT" } ["cookies":protected]=> array(0) { } ["lastHeader":protected]=> string(4) "date" ["body":protected]=> string(1157) "{"regions":[{"regionId":"R1","regionName":"TARAPACA","ineRegionCode":1},{"regionId":"R2","regionName":"ANTOFAGASTA","ineRegionCode":2},{"regionId":"R3","regionName":"ATACAMA","ineRegionCode":3},{"regionId":"R4","regionName":"COQUIMBO","ineRegionCode":4},{"regionId":"R5","regionName":"VALPARAISO","ineRegionCode":5},{"regionId":"R6","regionName":"LIBERTADOR GRAL BERNARDO O HIGGINS","ineRegionCode":6},{"regionId":"R7","regionName":"MAULE","ineRegionCode":7},{"regionId":"R8","regionName":"BIOBIO","ineRegionCode":8},{"regionId":"R9","regionName":"ARAUCANIA","ineRegionCode":9},{"regionId":"RM","regionName":"METROPOLITANA DE SANTIAGO","ineRegionCode":13},{"regionId":"R10","regionName":"LOS LAGOS","ineRegionCode":10},{"regionId":"R11","regionName":"AISEN DEL GRAL C IBANEZ DEL CAMPO","ineRegionCode":11},{"regionId":"R12","regionName":"MAGALLANES Y LA ANTARTICA CHILENA","ineRegionCode":12},{"regionId":"R14","regionName":"LOS RIOS","ineRegionCode":14},{"regionId":"R15","regionName":"ARICA Y PARINACOTA","ineRegionCode":15},{"regionId":"R16","regionName":"NUBLE","ineRegionCode":16}],"statusCode":0,"statusDescription":"Extraccion exitosa","errors":null}" ["bodyEncoded":protected]=> bool(true) }

Al realizar un

```
echo count($regiones);
```

**Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in C:\wamp64\www\ecuservi\prueba2.php on line 20
1**

Me gustaría crear un input select con cada elemento de la variable $regiones, pero al no tratarse de un array no se como recorrerlo con un ciclo for

Comment: Hola. Lo que sucede es que tu respuesta tiene formato JSON, para poder procesarla como un arreglo debes decodificarlo, puedes usar `$regiones = json_decode($response->getBody(),true);`

Comment: muchas gracias por tu respuesta, me sirvió